# What are the practical implications of properties and methods being moved to other interfaces in web API?

Tags: javascript, svg, webapi, pathelement

In https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement, the note says this:

***Note:*** In SVG 2 the getPathSegAtLength() and createSVGPathSeg* methods were removed and the pathLength property and the getTotalLength() and getPointAtLength() methods were moved to SVGGeometryElement.

What are the practical implications of this? So far I'm doing, for instance:

document.getElementById("myPath") --> myPath.isPointInStroke()

and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path, rect, circle, ellipse, polygon, polyline and line elements all derive from [SVGGraphicsElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement) in SVG 2. Moving methods from SVGPathElement to SVGGraphicsElement makes them available to all subclasses.

So in SVG 2 you can call getTotalLength() on a circle, which will cause the browser to return 2πr, whereas in SVG 1.1 you could only get the total length of a path element.

Comment: Do I understand then that the change does not really change the way you'd use it (call it on an a path element), but basically it was "moved up" in the chain so its methods apply to more diverse elements?